# looking for vector-like class with inner boundary checking

Tags: c++, exception, vector

I I'm looking for vector-like class which has inner boundary checking, for instance, I hope the following code throw an the exception and output "Catch Error".

Thanks

```
#include<vector>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    try
    {
        vector<int> vT(10,0);
        int cap = vT.capacity();
        cout << cap << endl;
        vT[cap] = 1;
        cout << vT[cap] << endl;
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        cout << "Catch Error" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's why it provides `at` (against size): http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at or are you really wanting to check capacity? If so, why?

Comment: Do you really want to use capacity? Or do you want to know the number of stored items in the container( size )?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just use the `std` collections, but use the [`..::at(cap)`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/at/) function iso the `operator[]`.  `at` throws when no element is present there.

Comment: I haven't realized that the vector::at can be placed on the left of the assignment.I thought it only can be used for reading, couldn't for assigning